# Google AppEngine Python Cron job urllib

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

I'm in need of setting up a cron job using Google AppEngine which will use urllib2 to execute a web page hosted on another server of mine.

I know that the script is executing (checked the logs) but my logging inside my python script never seems to be outputted.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util

import logging
import urllib
import urllib2

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        logging.info('Starting backups.')


def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)],
                                         debug=True)
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)
    urlStr = "http://example.com/cron.php"

    request = urllib2.Request(urlStr)
    try:
            response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
            logging.info("Backup complete!")
    except URLError, e:
            logging.error('There was an error %s', e.reason)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Can anyone see anything wrong with this?

Comment: fwiw, you're probably better off explicitly using the urlfetch API instead of urllib; you have more control over, e.g., timeouts, the the urllib support is really designed for compatibility with existing libraries rather than using directly in your code.

Comment: Thanks Wooble, I'll make sure I use it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`main()` should end after `util.run_wsgi_app(application)`. The rest of that belongs in your handler class.

Comment: Output or logged? You're not emitting anything to the HTTP response.

Comment: Use self.response.out.write(msg) in your handler to output something.

Answer (score 0):

I just used `main.py` from the Google App Engine root and then this seems to give me a better result.

There was a few problems other than what Drew mentioned too.

Comment: Can you be specific about the other problems, so anyone else encountering the same issues will find your question helpful?