# Google App Engine Python Cron

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email, cron, urllib

I've been trying for a few days now to get Google App Engine to run a cron Python script which will simply execute a script hosted on a server of mine.

It doesn't need to post any data to the page, simply open a connection, wait for it to finish then email me.

The code I've previously written has logged as "successful" but I never got an email, nor did I see any of the `logging.info` code I added to test things.

Ideas?

The original *and wrong code that I originally wrote can be found at* [Google AppEngine Python Cron job urllib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909054/google-appengine-python-cron-job-urllib) - just so you know I have attempted this before.

Comment: Isn't this an exact duplicate of your earlier question?

Comment: No because I didn't actually get the Cron job running, I in fact got the log to say it was "Success" in running. But it didn't do anything.

Comment: So how has your code changed since? Show us your new code! Also, what happens when you run the script manually, by going to it in your browser?

Comment: It hasn't really. It downloads the .py file.

Comment: Downloads what .py file? The code in your other question doesn't do anything like that. Did you implement the recommendation of the accepted answer in the other question? You shouldn't be doing real work in the `main()` method - everything should be done in the handler. What happens when you run the script manually?

Comment: This is definitely an exact duplicate of your other question - it's the same problem.

Comment: @Nick, I've also tried it that way. Also, should I be able to run it from my PC under IDLE *arguments sake*?

Comment: @James Don't just try it that way - that's the only way to do it. You shouldn't be doing anything in main() other than calling your webapp. And no, you shouldn't be able to run it from IDLE as a command line script - you need to run it inside dev_appserver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mix of weird things was happening here.

Firstly, `app.yaml` I had to place my `/cron` handler before the root was set:

```
handlers:
- url: /cron
  script: assets/backup/main.py

- url: /
  static_files: assets/index.html
  upload: assets/index.html
```

Otherwise I'd get crazy errors about not being able to find the file. That bit actually makes sense.

The next bit was the Python code. Not sure what was going on here, but in the end I managed to get it working by doing this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
# import logging
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.api import mail
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

import logging

class CronMailer(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        logging.info("Backups: Started!")
        urlStr = "http://example.com/file.php"

        rpc = urlfetch.create_rpc()
        urlfetch.make_fetch_call(rpc, urlStr)
        mail.send_mail(sender="example@example.com",
            to="email@example.co.uk",
            subject="Backups complete!",
            body="Daily backups have been completed!")
        logging.info("Backups: Finished!")

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/cron', CronMailer)],debug=True)
def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Whatever it was causing the problems, it's now fixed.